# Couldn't have put VS couldn't put

Tags: perfect-aspect, present-tense, could

Today I came across the following phrase:

> He **couldn't have put** it better, when he said: "..."

But why does it require perfect tense? Can it be replaced with simple tense instead?

> He **couldn't put** it better, when he said: "..."

For me it sounds like these two actions (*put* and *said*) happened at the same point in the past (i.e. simple) - why perfect then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your lecturer is standing over you and judging your work, then you might hear.

*"I say, Hexus, that's good, I couldn't put it better myself."*

But your example refers to the past.  "**He said...**"  in that case it has to be "**...couldn't have put...**"

*"He couldn't have put it better, when he said: "...""*

The page which @tchrist directs you to is excellent, and when you have a couple of hours to spare have a look. The analysis however is not aimed at those seeking a tidy, or a quick, solution.

Comment: One quick question though, just to make sure I got it correctly: 
the phrase I asked about - does it mean that he couldn't have put it better *before* he said it? Like, he was trying to find proper words, but couldn't and then eventually he managed to find and express them?

Comment: He got it right. **"..."** is the perfect phrase. All you can tell for certain is that it is **(a)** in the past, which may mean one second ago or several days ago; **(b)** he got it right; it may have jumped into his head or he may have sweated over the answer for hours.